# only enter localhost to invoke my servlet

Tags: servlets

I am writing a servlet. The servlet is using the URL pattern like this:
localhost/applicationname/myservletname

I want the user of myservlet only need to type in localhost in the browser and it will be directed to my servlet.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: The part `/myservletname` is easy, but the part `/applicationname` depends on server used. So if you tell which server runtime you're targeting your webapp to, then your question can be answered.

Comment: I am using glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using eclipse and tomcat.

1. Views -> Servers
2. double click on tomcat serve.
3. You'll see "Modules" Tab just over servers view.
4. Select your application and press edit.
5. In Path field, enter "/"

Now, your application will be executed on tomcat root by eclipse.

Then, you can just set your servlet's url-pattern (either by annotation or in web.xml) to "index.html"

All done, now when you will run your project, it won't require application name after localhost.